# Trying to solve problem with maps and lambdas

Tags: python, arrays, list, lambda

I´m trying to solve a problem using maps and lambdas but I never pass all the tests, just like 95% of them only.

The problem is:

"Given two integer arrays a, b, both of length >= 1, create a program that returns true if the sum of the squares of each element in a is strictly greater than the sum of the cubes of each element in b."

This is my code:

```
def array_madness(a,b):
    if sum(list(map(lambda num: num**2, a))) > sum(list(map(lambda num: num**2, b))):
        return True
    return False
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to `cube` the elements in `b`: `num**3`

Comment: As an aside, don't do `sum(list(map(...)))`, that defeats space-efficient nature of `map`, just do `sum(map(...))`. Also, a stylistic point, but `if <something>: return True else: return False` should just be `return <something>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
return sum(map(lambda num: num**2, a)) > sum(map(lambda num: num**3, b))
```

You're asked for the *cubes* of the elements in `b`. Also, there's no need to convert the result of `map` into a list, `sum` works fine on it as it is. And you don't need to use an `if` here, simply return the result of the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

```
def array_madness(a,b):
if sum(list(map(lambda num: num**2, a))) > sum(list(map(lambda num: num**2, b))):
    print (True)
else:
    print (False)
```

Above green tick answer by lopez, won't print anything as return would only store a value. printing has to be invoked. Please try this if statement. It worked for me.

Like array_madness([4,2],[5])

Comment: This is bad advice. When writing a _function_, in general you're not supposed to _print_ the result, it's preferred to _return_ a value and let the caller decide if it wants to print it or not. Return does not "store" a value.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I saw the problem, I wrote square numbers and not cube numbers in the second lambda